# Error: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is undefined

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to install Vue.js 3 and BootstrapVue with the doc of BootstrapVue.

My app build but Vue don't load. I can't understand why...

Thanks in advance if you have any ideas :)

I did (like in the documentation): [vue-cli-3](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#vue-cli-3)

1. vue create my-app
   cd my-app
   vue add bootstrap-vue
2. npm run serve
3. Error: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is undefined

The created main.js:

```js
import '@babel/polyfill'
import 'mutationobserver-shim'
import './plugins/bootstrap-vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Comment: I understand, bootstrap-vue need vue.js v2.6, not v3+.